# Search for people who have NOT registered for an event

Tags: civievent, search

I am trying to search for any person within a specified group in Civi that has NOT registered for a specific event.  The intention is to then send them all an e-mail to ask why they have not yet registered, encourage registration, etc.

I'm stumped as to how to search for people who have not registered for an event.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, create a group of people who have registered.  Next, go to **Search menu > Custom Searches**, and select Include/Exclude by Group/Tag. Include the group of people who should have registered, exclude those who have already registered, and there's your list.

I believe you can also do a similar include/exclude search using Search Builder in Civi 4.6, but this was broken in earlier versions so I haven't tried.